# Contentful getAsset retunrs undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, contentful

I am trying to get an asset, an image, from Contentful into my Angular app. While in the Network log I get the images, it keeps saysing `undefined` in my console.log. Any idea why?

Here is the function in the component:

```js
    this.contentfulService.getContactImage()
      .then(asset => this.pageImage)
      .then(asset => console.log("Recieved Gallery Image", this.pageImage));
```

Here is the service:

```js
  //get Page Image
  getContactImage() {
    return this.cdaClient.getAsset('<asset ID>')
      .then(asset => asset.fields.file.url);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont you think, you are returning `this.pageImage` that you never assign..

```
this.contentfulService.getContactImage()
      .then(asset => **this.pageImage**)
      .then(asset => console.log("Recieved Gallery Image", this.pageImage));
```